# Как поменять цвет ползунка slider в jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что прописать для .slider в css, чтобы изменить цвет ползунка? Может опять какие то библиотеки не подгрузил..

```js
var sum = 0, mon = 0;

$('#sum').slider({min:0.1, max:5, step: 0.05,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {sum=ui.value; calc(sum,mon)}});
$('#mon').slider({min:2, max:12, 
    slide: function( event, ui ) {mon=ui.value; calc(sum,mon)}});

function calc(sum,mon){
   $('#get').val( (sum*(1+(0.025*mon))).toFixed(2) );
   $('#sumv').html(sum);
   $('#monv').html(mon);
}
```

```css
body 
{
    background-color: black;
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #5cb85c;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#sum, #mon {
  width: 200px; margin-left: 10%;
}
#sumv, #monv {
  padding-left: 40px; margin-left: 10%
}
#get {
  font-weight: bold; font-size: 14pt; height: 30px; width: 50px; margin-left: 10%; text-align: center; color: #5cb85c;
}
```

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Если цвет ползунка нужен разный в зависимости от его местоположения, можно адаптировать этот пример под себя: https://codepen.io/agcolom/pen/jtHmv

Comment: Интересно, спасибо, но пока тяжеловато для меня)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если поменять цвет самого ползунка, то -

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default {
  background: red;
}
```

Если поменять цвет линии, по которой ходит ползунок, то -

```
 .ui-widget-content {
   background: red;
 }
```

Только подключайте ваш файл со стилями после файла стилей этой библиотеки